# Binning data with overlapping bins

Tags: python, histogram, binning

I need to binning wind data

The idea is to vary the wind bins size so each bin can cover a minimun amount of data.Then at the end I will have 360 overlapping bins

Therefore a need to define the lower and upper limit of the bins and vary the upper limit afterwards according to the data that fall into the different bins

np.digitize seems to work only with 1 dimensional bins

so this was my try:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

#initially equal size bins[[lower limit], [upper limit]]
bins=np.array([[np.arange(0,360)], [np.arange(1,361)]])

#dfIn is a vector with angles from 0 to 360
index_Rdir= binned_statistic(dfIn, dfIn, bins=bins)
```

then the rest of the algorithm in which the frequency of data 
in each bin is calculated and the upper limit of the bin increased 
for those bins which do not get a minimun of data...

when trying to binning with binned_statistic raise the following error

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2973 to array axis with dimension 3
```

If instead of one array for the bins I try with a list, I got the similar error.

I tried also with np.histogram as according to documentation allows non uniform bin size

```
index_Rdir= np.histogram(dfIn,  bins=bins)

all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: I am not sure you can get overlapping bins natively, since [`bins must be monotonically increasing or decreasing`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c). Furthermore, [`binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) also allows non-uniform bin size.

Comment: Yes now that i am rereading the documentation I think I will have to rewrite the code in another way. Probably doing 360 calculations with bins =[0-1] then bins=[1,2] and so on. It is the only way I can figure out to do such a calculation